# Looking for Geoserver REST PHP examples

Tags: geoserver, rest, php

I am in deadly need of geoserver rest php scripts for creating workspace, store, publishing layer etc. I have done a lot of googleing but couldn't find any. In geoserver site only examples using cURL are given. Can anybody provide me PHP scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geoserver REST API can be constructed using

Path
GET (read)
POST (create)
PUT (update)
DELETE (delete)

http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/User+Collaboration+REST+API

for selecting a SLD you need to GET {yourserver} {port} {user} {password}

/geoserver/rest/styles (exists already in rest api)

This might help for you too
http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoExt+Styler

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-php.html

Comment: It has only scripts to create a workspace. What about creating a store,publishing a layer and selecting a sld?? where can I find thesE?