# GeoServer create a datastore using PHP and the REST API

Tags: php, geoserver-rest-api

First of all I hope you forgive my bad English,I'm trying to create a datastore in GeoServer using PHP so can you please give me an example that can guide me to achieve it.

The code I have is:

```
$app->match('/send', function() use ($app){
$curl = new Curl();
$encoder =  [new XmlEncoder('datastore'), new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder()];
$normalizer = [new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer()];
$serializer = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);
$service = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/"; // replace with your URL
$reqt = "rest/workspaces.xml"; // to add a new workspace
$url = $service . $reqt;
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_POST, True);
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('admin', 'geoserver');
$json = json_encode($curl->get($url));
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

if($request->isMethod('POST')){
    $params  = [
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'type' => 'GeoTIFF',
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'url' => __DIR__ . '/' .$file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'enabled' => 'on' == $request->get('enabled') ? 'true' : 'false',

    ];
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE);
    $json = $app['serializer']->serialize($data, 'json');      
    $curl->setHeader("Content-type"," application/json");
    $target = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{$request->get('workspace')}/datastores";
    return new Response($curl->post($target, $json));
}

return $app['twig']->render('form.html.twig', ['data' => array_shift($data)]);
})->bind('send');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [some PHP REST samples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/php.html) already mentioned at [this other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10815/looking-for-geoserver-rest-php-examples) but links are dead.

You can also use the samples at [IBM DeveloperWorks "Get started with GeoServer and its REST API"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-geoserver/) (to download and in the post).

Comment: Thanks for your help :) i will use the php wrapper and add some things on it maybe